# How can I export the HTML table with nested tables to Excel correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have HTML table with nested tables. I need to export it to Excel. For this purpose, I use libraries XLSX and FileSaver.

There's a code of table:

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" class="excelTable" ref="excelTable">
      <thead>
        <tr align="center">
          <td width="9%">Табельный №</td>
          <td width="18%">ФИО работника</td>
          <td width="8%">Должность</td>
          <td width="20%">Датчик Луч4</td>
          <td width="14%">Наличие отклонений от маршрута</td>
          <td width="9%">Маршрут</td>
          <td width="12%">% обследования маршрута</td>
          <td>Фактическое время</td>
          <td>Протяженность маршрута</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody v-for="department in routesHandbook" :key="department.department_id">
        <tr bgcolor="#b6b6b6">
          <th colspan="9">{{ department.title }}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="9">
            <table class="inner__table" border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
              <tbody v-for="worker in department.workers" :key="worker.worker_id">
                <tr align="center">
                  <td width="8.5%">
                    <span>{{ worker.tabNumber }}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td width="16.5%">
                    <span>{{ worker.fio }}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td width="7.8%">
                    <span>{{ worker.post }}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td width="18.1%">
                    <span>{{ worker.sensorRayTitle }}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td width="13%">
                    <span v-if="worker.routeDeviation===true">Да</span>
                    <span v-else>Нет</span>
                  </td>
                  <td width="8.5%">
                    <span>{{ worker.routeTitle }}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td width="11.6%">
                    <span>{{ worker.routePercent }}%</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span>{{ worker.factTime }}, мин</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span>{{ worker.routeLength }}, метр</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="9">
                    <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
                      <thead>
                        <tr bgcolor="#b6b6b6" align="center">
                          <td width="6%">По маршруту?</td>
                          <td width="15%">Место</td>
                          <td width="20%">Наименование датчика</td>
                          <td width="13%">Дата и время</td>
                          <td width="8%">Показание датчика</td>
                          <td width="15%">Дата и время</td>
                          <td width="7%">Показание датчика ЛУЧ-4</td>
                          <td>Превышение ПДК</td>
                          <td>Расхождения в показаниях</td>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr align="center" v-for="place in worker.places" :key="place.place_id">
                          <td width="6%">
                            <span v-if="place.routeCheck===true">Да</span>
                            <span v-else>Нет</span>
                          </td>
                          <td width="15%">
                            <span>{{ place.title }}</span>
                          </td>
                          <td width="20%">
                            <span>{{ place.sensorTitle }}</span>
                          </td>
                          <td width="13%">
                            <span>{{ place.sensorDate }} {{ place.sensorTime }}</span>
                          </td>
                          <td width="8%">
                            <span v-if="place.sensorPercent!=''">{{ place.sensorPercent }}%</span>
                            <span v-else>-</span>
                          </td>
                          <td width="15%">
                            <span>{{ place.sensorRayDate }} {{ place.sensorRayTime }}</span>
                          </td>
                          <td width="7%">
                            <span v-if="place.sensorRayPercent!=''">{{ place.sensorRayPercent }}%</span>
                            <span v-else>-</span>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <span v-if="place.excessPDK===true">Да</span>
                            <span v-else>Нет</span>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <span>{{ sensorsDifference(place) }}</span>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

And there's a code of export:

```js
exportToExcel() {
      // экспорт данных в Excel
      let excelTable = this.$refs.excelTable;

      let ws = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(excelTable);
      const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

      let wscols = [
        {
          wch: 20
        },
        {
          wch: 20
        },
        {
          wch: 20
        },
        {
          wch: 20
        },
        {
          wch: 20
        },
        {
          wch: 20
        },
        {
          wch: 20
        },
        {
          wch: 20
        },
        {
          wch: 20
        }
      ];
      let wsrows = [
        {
          hpx: 40
        }
      ];
      ws["!cols"] = wscols;
      ws["!rows"] = wsrows;

      XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Sheet JS");

      const wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {
        bookType: "xlsx",
        bookSST: true,
        type: "binary"
      });

      let blob = new Blob([this.s2ab(wbout)], {
        type: "application/octet-stream"
      });

      saveAs(blob, "Сравнение маршрутов.xlsx");
    }
```

All works fine, but some non-existing rows appear and their columns mix with each other [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oUhU.jpg).

Why does it happen? And how can I fix it?

P.S. Sorry for russian language, I'm just from Russia)

Comment: Unescaped characters like commas and quotes will cause issues with your column formatting. You should sanitize your inputs to escape commas and quotes.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda You mean commas and quotes in table cells? Ok, I deleted them, saved file again and nothing changed.

Comment: Yep you seem to have malformed data somewhere in your HTML table. I can't see the full excel files so it's hard to pinpoint which value is giving you issues. Check the value in the cell right before you see an issue

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda No, all seems fine. Maybe nested tables cause this issue?

Comment: Sorry, looks like SheetJS does not support exporting nested tables: https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/1724

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Aah, I got it, thanks...But how can I export my data in Excel? From JSON?

My main object with data is complicated, and some properties are nested objects. Will SheetJs work fine with it?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't handle nested JSON either unfortunately (https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/1213) you'll need to flatten your data to export it into Excel.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Cool...anyway, thx a lot!